# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden on IIS8 Server. However, Working on local VS2013(IISExpress)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, iis-8

I have mvc 4 ASP.net 4.5 web application say **version1** which was initially developed using visual studio 2013. Version1 has successfully deployed on IIS8 which is up and running without any issues.

We got a requirement to update version1 to version2. Which was implemented and tested on visual studio 2013 on local machine where everything is working fine.
This point may help, While implementing version2 we used vs2015 for some time and rolled back to vs2013. Now we moved version2 to IIS8 as a **separate website**(Not updated version1) on same IIS8 where version1 is hosted.

Now version2 is throwing below error while trying to access: 
**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

Tried different below suggestions from other blog but did not rectify the issue:

1 Adding to web config file:

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

2 Running Below:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

3 Tried:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

4 Uncheck or check "**Precompile During Publishing**" option while extracting the package.

5 RouteConfig.cs file also looks file

```
$public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "StartUpPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the actual fix or reason for this error.

But turn around is creating new workspace and copying old project set to new workspace. Finally publishing it to web server did not throw this error.

Might be some problem with my workspace or settings while exporting package.